# Stream data from C++ to MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, logging, stream

I have a C++ Windows application which interfaces with a micro-controller using UART, acting as a master and CLI to the system. The MCU can be set to "stream mode", such that it constantly sends data to the CLI, which is then parsed as necessary.

I'm trying to create a MATLAB application (maybe even a GUI) that should receive the parsed data from the CLI and do something with it, such as plotting the data.

How would I "stream" the data from my CLI application to some MATLAB instance. I'm thinking of writing the data to a file whilst reading from it, but that seems like a non-optimal solution.

Comment: Any way you could write that data to a virtual com port? Even that would be easier, otherwise you're looking for synchronization troubles. Also, do you _have to_ use MATLAB for this?

Comment: Depends how much configuration a virtual port requires? And the end goal is PID controller tuning, analysis etc., so preferably MATLAB, yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way to do this is to open a TCP/IP socket in the C++ program and send the data there. On your MATLAB app you should open a socket and receive the data.
I'm not familiar how this can be done in MATALB (I'm sure it is), need someone who know to add some insight here :)

Another option is to use MATLAB's built in MEX function interface to C/C++ programs. man: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html?searchHighlight=MEX&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

Comment: I think that MEX is the way to go. I had actually looked into it, but misunderstood it the first time... after a bit more digging it seems like the correct choice, gonna give i a try! Thanks.